# How would I go about making water shoot out of a pipe rather than just flow out?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I am working on a project that requires the water to shoot out of the end of the pipe rather than what it is doing right. Now, I have played with some of the settings but am kinda afraid to mess with it too much since I am new to blender, and it does not play well when I mindlessly click.

Would I generate more fluid particles? Or would I change some property about the inflow animation? I added a cylinder object to the top of the pipe as well, I think that will help keep all the water inside of the pipe.

Thank you once again and have a great day!

Comment: you have no fluid particles at all. Neither do you have an inflow animation. I think what you mean is Meshresolution and Fluid Physics as Inflow

Comment: Is your Pipe transparent?

Comment: Consider adding your .blend file to the question, it might be helpful in experimenting with the correct settings.

Comment: Please be clear if you are using particles and what type, or a fluid simulation, or something else.  Please show your settings in  Blender screen capture.  The reader should be able to see something more since you are asking for details from the reader.  For example I used particles in a candidate answer below.  Yet I am still not sure what techniques you have used.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If you don't need a physically accurate simulation or continuity with the water coming out of the pipe you could fake it with particles instead.

Use a particle system on an emitter placed at the end of the tube (a simple plane should suffice).

Add a Metaball object as particle object, adjust size and resolution as desired. You can then control how far the water jet shoots by controlling the *Velocity > Normal* property of the particle system.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I have the plane in place, but I need the water to be shooting out of the tube like a fire hose rather than what you have above which is more similar to a garden hose. How can I fix that?

Comment: @IdealTechHelp It should be pretty easy to adjust the particle settings to get what you want. You want the Normal velocity to be set pretty high it sounds like. If you want it to break up some, then try some Brownian or maybe even a noise/turbulence field. If you do not want any gravity, try turning it down/off in the particle settings (Field Weights)

Comment: You should add reference images of the effect you are trying to achieve to your question. In that case you could probably loose the Metaballs and just increase the particle velocity. Perhaps even turn off gravity effect

Comment: https://imgur.com/K084fgW

Comment: @duarte So after turning off gravity, what would I do to increase the particle velocity? Would that be in reference to the inflow object, or the domain?

Comment: Inflow objects and domains are fluid simulation elements, not particles. My suggestion uses a pure particle system. Just increase the *Normal* velocity parameter for that particle system.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos https://imgur.com/a/Fpglk2k I am trying to find that normal velocity perameter, and have converted this the metaball object into a mesh, but no water is coming out of it. Can you help?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+particles+water

Answer (score 1):

**Use more irregular mesh for your particles to increase the variety and increase spray like effect**

[image]

- The emitter mesh has multiple islands.  Portions of a UV Sphere.  Normals are displayed in edit mode.
- Use Multiple Particle systems to increase variety.    For example a second Particle System could have different normal multipliers.  Normal Multipliers can be animated.
- I will let you experiment with Fluid Particles.