# creating a dry fountain

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to create a dry fountain in Blender (see the reference image). However, I have no luck so far. I've added a small circle to my scene, which I made the inflow for the fluid simulation. I then created a fluid domain and pressed 'bake'. The result is very poor: no water is created at all. Can anyone please suggest a more effective way to create a dry fountain?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more info. What do you mean by very poor? Post your fluid settings or scene file.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134901/how-would-i-go-about-making-water-shoot-out-of-a-pipe-rather-than-just-flow-out/134906#134906

Comment: I'm relatively new to the fluid modifier, so I have left everything at default value and just added an inflow at the base of the fountain and a domain. I would be much helped if you could explain how you would go about recreating the fountain in my picture.

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question, if you want to add information. Don't use the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your fluid inflow has a velocity in the correct direction, and your fluid inflow object is filled (try using a sphere rather than a circle if it doesn't work) Check out one of the basic fluid tutorials on YouTube, as the majority of the techniques you need for this kind of simulation are covered there.