# How can I imitate Shang Chi's end credit sequence?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Recently watched the [end credit sequence of Shang Chi](https://streamable.com/xyf08f), the flowy water one.

It inspired me to try Blender, because I saw [this guy go for an imitation that looked half decent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yYNw4Ugrg8). I'm a beginner but I finished Blender Guru's tutorials and I'm feeling ready to take on this challenge.

I'm wondering if this community could give me some guidance on how to copy what the animators did with the watery objects.

Specifically, given any object that I want to convert into this style, how do I make it act like suspended, moving water, like all of the objects in the video that don't immediately fall to the ground?

Comment: just a note, water sims and water like materials are really demanding on hardware, make sure that this won't be the thing that will stop you eventually and don't try what your PC won't handle... Anyway, the way that youtube did it is simply giving his rigged characters material that looks like water (more like glass in this settings) and he used emissions or water sims to make effects. Can it be done? Yes it can... However I am not sure about that part of something growing from water, maybe you could do it with geometry nodes that are becoming more and more useful in 3.0.0+

Comment: I am unfortunately stuck on the ideation stage because I know nothing of where to start. I'll report back after trying some more. Thank you @MikoCG, I have a NVidia 30 series card so hopefully I can handle this.

Comment: Just to clarify it for you, simulation are not done by GPU, CPU is doing physics and simulations, GPu will only render video of it for you but baking and all calculation for water particles are done by your CPU

Comment: Hi Kevin, i like your question and i vote for reopen, but you should ask only 1 question ...so please open 3 others and just copy the text and put just one question at the end. These are the rules. I didn't make them. I don't like them either. But if you want your question to be reopened ....you should do it. This is an advice from a guy who has gone through that shit too...the hard way....

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134901/how-would-i-go-about-making-water-shoot-out-of-a-pipe-rather-than-just-flow-out/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object/